# Check if data came back from firebase using angular2

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have the following code to load data from my firebase which works but it is painfully ugly.

```
loadData() {

    // app.component
    this.loadJobCodeSubscription = this.databaseService.getData()
    .subscribe(result => {

        this.data = null;
        var data_raw: Array<any>;

        if (Object.keys(result)[0] != '$value') {
        data_raw = Object.keys(result).map(function (key) {
            return [key, result[key]['firstName'], result[key]['lastName']];
        })

        // remove extra data downloaded from firebase
        jobDataRaw.pop();
        jobDataRaw.pop();
        }

        this.jobCodeData = jobDataRaw;

    }, error => {
        console.log('Error downloading job codes', error)
    })
}

// DatabaseService
getData() {
    return this.af.database.object('/jobCodes/' + this.currentUser.company)
}
```

What happens is that if the branch I am querying does not have data, my "result" will display

[image: empty]

Andi if I have data coming back, I will get something like

[image: not empty]

The only difference (that I can think of to check for) between these two data is that one has a $value key and one does not
That is why I am using that weird if statement to check if that key exists.

Is there a way to check for data in a neater way?

Also, is there a way to cast 'result' to the right format as oppose to 'any' which it currently is

Note. I am using Angular 2 with AngularFire2

Answer (score 0):

First, presuming you have control of the backend, you could alter the return to be more easily understandable.  Returning an empty payload is a bit confusing if you really mean "nothing".

Second, dangerous to do this line:

`Object.keys(result)[0]`

As Object.keys(result) may not be the same in the future, even though it may be deterministic.

I think the safest way to do this would be:

```
if (Object.keys(result).every(k => k != '$value')) {
```

That being said, I don't think there's an easier way to determine that given the information you've presented.  If you continue with this approach, it would be good to make sure you are guarding your statements carefully, as it seems like 
bad data could slip through in the future.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have control over firebase

Comment: Then this is probably your best bet.

Comment: I am guessing and hoping there might be a way to cast result to some sort of firebase structure and do something like result.hasData or something.... Thanks by the way

Comment: See my answer if you are interested. Turns out that I could alter what come back. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that if I change the return type of the observable to be the original firebase snapshot, the data looks much better. It allows me to call if(snapshot.val()){}

```
return this.af.database.object('/jobCodes/' + this.currentUser.company, {preserveSnapshot: true})
```